# How to get the value of children in Firebase Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my Firebase Database:

[image: firebase database]

I need the URLs of the images that are associated alongside the unique random name generated by the push method. Is there any way I could do that? Also, there must exist a better way of sending data. Please, let me know. Thanks.

```
imgRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

This is, as expected, returning the entire JSON object. I need the URL.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is the most basic way to show the list of image URLs:

```
var rootRef = firebase.database.ref();
var urlRef = rootRef.child("user1/DAA Notes/URL");
urlRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log(child.key+": "+child.val());
  });
});
```

Comment: This will give you the full list. What if you just want  the third item of that list?

Comment: How to do that in typescript?

Comment: All JavaScript is valid TypeScript, so the above will work in a `.ts` file too.