# Get child of snapshot of deleted node

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Here is my Firebase structure:

```
{ 
"HeCc6ha5g9VO6VSzHH63kkbJMa82": {
    "budgets",
    "dailyHabits",
    "dailyJobs",
    "householdInformation": {
        "email": "bob@bob.com",
        "initialDownload": 123456789
    },
    "purchases": {
        123456789: {
            "price": 9.99
            "product": "stuff"
            "subExpDate": 123456789
        }
    }
}
```

When the admin deletes the top node (HeCc6ha5g9VO6VSzHH63kkbJMa82), I want to grab the email address and use it to update my mail service and delete the user from there, too. In short, if a user is deleted off of Firebase, I want to also delete them from my mail service as well.

WHAT I'VE TRIED:

```
exports.sendinblueDeleteUser = functions.database.ref('/users/{userID}')
.onDelete((snapshot: any, _context: any) => {

    const email = snapshot.child('householdInformation/email').val()

    // Then use that email to delete user from sendinblue servers //

})
```

I keep getting an error telling me that the value of email is null.

How do I get the child node of a snapshot and use it?

I've read the documentation [HERE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key) and [HERE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) and also looked at [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41291980/how-to-get-the-value-of-children-in-firebase-javascript) post, but I'm stuck. I know Swift pretty well but not Typescript.

I'm using VS Code and Typescript to access the Google Cloud Functions for my database, if that helps.

Comment: The `snapshot.child('householdInformation/email').val()` looks fine at first glance to me. If you get an error, I recommend logging `console.log(snapshot.val())` before the line that fails, and checking of it matches your expectation.

Comment: Thanks, @FrankvanPuffelen. So I tried it again, and it worked just fine. I swear I spent three hours on this stinking code! You must have the magic touch. :-)

Comment: Rubber duck debugging, or a heisenbug. I'm just glad the problem is gone for now! :)